# How to display Navbar In Webview (InAppBrowser) in IONIC?

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, navbar

I'm develop mobile with IONIC Cordova, and I'm very beginner in this.
I want to question how to display navbar in Page Webview, my page webview use InAppBrowser.

this is my page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>WV</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

this my page.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-wv',
  templateUrl: 'wv.html',
})
export class WvPage {

  my_url: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private IAB: InAppBrowser) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WvPage');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    const browser = this.IAB.create('http://myUrl.com/', '_self', {location: 'no'});
  }

}
```

Comment: You have to customize android and iOS code for plugin

Comment: can u explain how to customize it?

Comment: If you're talking about Ionic's Navbar, I don't think thats possible. Using the InAppBrowser, with `_self` param redirects the Webview your app is running in to `myUrl.com`.